# Disabling select option

Tags: jquery

The jQuery function which I use disables the possibility to select same select values on one page. For example: If I have on page 2 different selects and selected value on first select is 1, then on the second select, value 1 should be disabled. I found commentated jQuery function, but I don't the way it is functioning.

```
var previous = -1;
// Setting a previously selected value
$("select").change(function () {
// When any select element is changed
if ($(this).val() > -1) {
// When value is > -1
    // Get all selects but not the current one which triggered the change event
    $("select").not(this)
       .find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    // set the current option value to disabled

     // Get all selects but not the current one which triggered the change event
    $("select").not(this)
        .find("option[value=" + previous + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
    // Remove the disabled property on previous value
} else {
    // Get all selects but not the current one which triggered the change event
    $("select").not(this)
        .find("option[value=" + previous + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
    // Remove the disabled property
}
}).focus(function () {
previous = $(this).val();
// store the current value of the select to previous 
});
```

**Here is JSFiddle link:**http://jsfiddle.net/Z2yaG/4/

Can someone explain me is the var previous array? How does function stores values from all selects on var previous?

Comment: It doesn't. It only stores one value. If you [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners), you can set breakpoints and inspect the variables yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you focus on any select, `previous` gets the select value. and when you change, 
`$(this).val()` gets the changed value, and `previous` contans the previous value (the one before the change was made.

so, basically what your function does is, as soon as you select any option, it disables that option in the other two `selects`

`$("select").not(this)
       .find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

this line means, select all the `select` except for the current one, and `disable` the `option` with the value `this.val()`

and then it similarly enables the `previous` option, since that is not selected anymore

`$("select").not(this)
        .find("option[value=" + previous + "]").removeAttr('disabled');`

select all the `selects` except for `this` and remove the `disable` of all the `options` with the selected value